# Decidability of $2^a \bmod a^3$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, computability, decidability

From some limited testing, it seems to me like $2^a \bmod a^3$ has no repeat values except for some powers of $2$. More generally, it also seems that $x^a \bmod (a^3+k)$ often holds to this, although a few $x$ or $k$ values do get one early repeated non-$x$-power value.

I am guessing this is basically a probabilistic result, and that $a^3$ grows fast enough that repeats become vanishingly unlikely.

Is that correct?

And if so, is it fair to label that class of problem undecidable? My impression is that there is no other way to determine whether one of these outlier $a$ values exist other than trying increasingly large $a$ indefinitely hoping for a counterexample, which seems to fit with my understanding of undecidability.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by repeat values? And what is the problem you expect to be undecidable (in terms of input and output)?

Comment: Repeat values meaning e.g. $7^{34} \bmod 34^3=7^{44} \bmod 44^3=17185$. And I'm asking if for the class of functions $f(x,a)=x^a \bmod a^3$, whether it is undecidable in general to determine, given some $x$, whether there are two values of $a$ that yield equivalent $f(x,a)$ which is not a power of $x$. It seems like the only thing you can do is try to find counterexamples, as with $x=7$ and $a=\{34,44\}$ as above, but there's no way to be sure there isn't a counterexample without trying infinitely many $a$ values for a given $x$.